# Tikz addplot fill between depending on sign

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

i have following problem. I read data from a table and plot it and then fill the area between the x-axis and the curve. This works fine. Well at least a bit. I want the "negative part" filled in another color than the "positive part" of the curve. My Code looks sofar like this

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,open=any,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}
            [xlabel={$t$ [s]},ylabel={y}, xmin=0, xmax=140, ymin=-0.6, ymax=1.2, grid, width=14.5cm, height=7cm]
            \addplot plot [name path=A, color=black, mark=no] table{test.txt};
            \addplot[name path=B,black,mark=no,line width=0.01pt] coordinates  {(0,0) (1,0)};
            \addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=A and B];
            \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at section 5.6.4 Styles around Fillbetween from pgfplots documentation. There you can find styles like `every even segment` which can help you. If it doesn't, please show us what's the contents of `test.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for `fillbetween` library. You can plot twice your data but clipping the result above or below the y axis.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,open=any,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
0 0
16 0
16 0.125
44 0.125
44 0.25
56 0.25
56 -0.125
64 -0.125
64 0
80 0
80 0.125
104 0.125
104 0.25
116 0.25
116 -0.125
124 -0.125
124 0
140 0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}
            [xlabel={$t$ [s]},ylabel={y}, xmin=0, xmax=140, ymin=-0.6, ymax=1.2, grid, width=14.5cm, height=7cm]
%            \addplot plot [name path=A, color=black, mark=no] table{test.txt};
%            \addplot[name path=B,black,mark=no,line width=0.01pt, domain=0:140] {0};
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:140,1.2);
            \addplot plot [color=black, mark=no,fill=red] table{test.txt}\closedcycle;
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:140,-1.2);
            \addplot plot [color=black, mark=no,fill=green] table{test.txt}\closedcycle;
            \end{scope}
            \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `fillbetween` library needs the `split` option if it should apply different styles for different segments. In addition, the second path (`B` in your example) should have the same width as the first path. In your example, `B` spans only from x=0 to x=1 although the input data spans from 0 to 140.

Here is an example with `fillbetween`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}
            [xlabel={$t$ [s]},ylabel={y}, xmin=0, xmax=140, ymin=-0.6, ymax=1.2, grid, width=14.5cm, height=7cm]
            \addplot[name path=A, color=black] table{
0 0
16 0
16 0.125
44 0.125
44 0.25
56 0.25
56 -0.125
64 -0.125
64 0
80 0
80 0.125
104 0.125
104 0.25
116 0.25
116 -0.125
124 -0.125
124 0
140 0
            };
            \path[name path=B] (0,0) -- (150,0);
            \addplot[red] fill between[of=A and B,split,
                every segment no 1/.style={orange},
                every segment no 4/.style={orange},
            ];
            \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `fillbetween` actually fails if you use `every even segment/.style`: apparently, it counts the "empty" area with `y=0` as its own segment. I worked around this problem by means of explicitly provided segment indices (not very general, agreed...)

Note that `\path[name path=B] (0,0) -- (150,0);` is correct: it uses `pgfplots` units (starting with `compat=1.11`). Older versions need `(axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:150,0)`.